# Printing in the same line CMD

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmd

I am trying to print a message and then remove it and print something else. I tried this code and it works on PyCharm but doesn't work on CMD. Why does it not work and how do I make it work on CMD?

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\rbb')
sys.stdout.write('\ra\n')
```

Cmd Output:

```
>>> ab
```

PyCharm Output:
[image]

Comment: And why exactly do you expect this output?

Comment: Thats the output I get when I run it on Pycharm

Comment: Why should the *second* `b` disappear, simply because an `a` is drawn over top of the *first* one?

Comment: the second b disappears when I run it on PyCahrm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carriage return (`\r`) only returns cursor to beginning of the line. It has no semantics of "cleaning".

Everything else is up to terminal emulator to decide. In general,

```
print('first  line', end='\r')
print('second')
```

will result in

```
second line
```

---

Python 2 note: as `print` is statement in python2, you can use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the beginning of your file, to make `print` semantically identical in to py3

Comment: `print('first  line', end='\r')` is an Error in Python 2.7

Comment: @yoav In Python 2.7 you have to add `from __future__ import print_function` for this to work

Comment: @slam I still dont understand why it works on PyCharm and it doesnt work on the CMD.

Comment: Might be because the PyCharm terminal is in general a bit peculiar. I would not rely on it behaving like other "normal" TTYs. Have you tried turning on "Terminal Emulation" in the run config and see if it behaves differently?

Comment: @yoav that was exactly the point with "terminal decides". Every single terminal emulator can have it's own logic and rules of handling... well, everything. `\r` thing is just one of it. Looks like pycharm is "smart" enough to clear the line when you do caret return. For better or worse

Comment: Is there other way to do it without importing anythin in Python 2.7?

Comment: From the top of my head – no. Either you should use print functions, or `sys.stdout`